# Using custom shape type with the LWC Base Map Component

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-map

I am trying to implement the option of "Marking Locations with Shapes" in the LWC Base Map Component as outlined here:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-map/documentation

It works to a point (i.e. I see a circle with custom colors vs the standard Google Marker) but it seems to break other stuff like the click handler, and the pop up with title and description. I don't see that mentioned anywhere in the docs, so wondering if anyone else has gotten this to work, and if so, what I am doing wrong here?

```
  let maptemp = {};
  maptemp.location = {Latitude: record.LatLong__Latitude__s, Longitude: record.LatLong__Longitude__s};
                    maptemp.value = record.Id;
                    maptemp.title = record.Name;
                    maptemp.description = record.Location_Status__c;
                    maptemp.icon = 'standard:account';
                    maptemp.type = 'Circle';
                    maptemp.radius = 200;
                    maptemp.strokeColor = '#9900ff';//Purple
                    maptemp.fillColor = '#9900ff';//Purple                     
                    maptemp.strokeOpacity = 1.0;
                    maptemp.strokeWeight = 2;
                    maptemp.fillOpacity = 1.0;
                drainstemp.push(maptemp);
```

But actually works fine if you use the mapicon approach, so seems to be an issue with the type functionality:

```
mapIcon : {
                path: 'M 125,5 155,90 245,90 175,145 200,230 125,180 50,230 75,145 5,90 95,90 z',
                fillColor: '#CF3476',
                fillOpacity: .5,
                strokeWeight: 1,
                scale: .10,
```